# fixed width data into postgres

Tags: postgresql, upload, load, fixed-width

Looking for good way to load FIXED-Width data into postgres tables. I do this is sas and python not postgres. I guess there is not a native method. The files are a few GB. The one way I have seen does not work on my file for some reason (possibly memory issues). There you load as one large column and then parse into tables. I can use psycopy2 but because of memory issues would rather not. Any ideas or tools that work. Does pgloader work well or are there native methods?

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/157-Import-fixed-width-data-into-PostgreSQL-with-just-PSQL.html

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no convenient built-in method to ingest fixed-width tabular data in PostgreSQL. I suggest using a tool like Pentaho Kettle or Talend Studio to do the data-loading, as they're good at consuming many different file formats. I don't remember if `pg_bulkload` supports fixed-width, but suspect not.

Alternately, you can generally write a simple script with something like Python and the `psycopg2` module, loading the fixed-width data row by row and sending that to PostgreSQL. `psycopg2`'s support for the `COPY` command via `copy_from` makes this vastly more efficient. I didn't find a convenient fixed-width file reader for Python in a quick search but I'm sure they're out there. You can use whatever language you like anyway - Perl's `DBI` and `DBD::Pg` do just as well, and there are millions of fixed-width file reader modules for Perl.

Comment: In python, the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is designed to unpack heterogeneous data to a tuple based on a format string and thus it may be used to read a fixed-width text file.

Comment: @furins That's handy in combination with psycopg2 and `copy_from`

Comment: indeed! I used structs & iterators to bulk read large, legacy, fixed-text dumps in low-memory environments (django web-apps on shared hosting)

Answer (score 0):

The Python Pandas library has a function pandas.read_fwf which works great.

Data can be read in using python, then written to Postgres database.